# Python 2.7 Is there an equivalent method to locals formatting when adding class attributes into a string?

Tags: string, python-2.7, class

I have a class that has a number of attributes and within that class I have a function that combines those attributes into a string.

The string is quite long so for visual purposes, I would like to see exactly which variable is inserted where. The ideal solution is to use `"This is my %(self.var_name)s" %locals()` however the solution only works if I redefine my variable first. For example see the example script:

```
class Shopping(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n_apples = 4
        self.n_pears = 5
        self.n_grapefruit =7

    def generate_list_from_self(self):

        self.shoppingList = """ 
        My Shopping List
        apples = %(self.n_apples)s
        pears = %(self.n_pears)s
        grapefruits = %(self.n_grapefruit)s
        """ %locals()

    def generate_list_redefine_variables(self):

        n_apples = self.n_apples
        n_pears = self.n_pears
        n_grapefruit = self.n_grapefruit

        self.shoppingList = """ 
        My Shopping List
        apples = %(n_apples)s
        pears = %(n_pears)s
        grapefruits = %(n_grapefruit)s
        """ %locals()


shopping = Shopping()

# First method
shopping.generate_list_from_self()

# Second method
shopping.generate_list_redefine_variables()
```

The ideal solution would be to use the `generate_from_self()` method but the variables are not picked up by `%locals()`. Instead I am using the second approach and redefining the variables locally before inserting them into the string. This seems cumbersome and I am wondering if there is a better way of achieving this?

It is crucial that I am able to see where the variable is inserted into the string as the string I am working with gets very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the simple approach will be changing the first method to:

```
 def generate_list_from_self(self):
     self.shoppingList = """ 
     My Shopping List
     apples = %(n_apples)s
     pears = %(n_pears)s
     grapefruits = %(n_grapefruit)s
     """ %vars(self)
```

here i used the [vars method](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#vars)

in general it's common to use [__str__(self)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) for this approach ( converting your class to string) but since there is an init of `self.shoppingList`  i am not sure this is the right approach for you. but i'll reference you anyway to an implementation of this:

```
class Shopping(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.n_apples = 4
         self.n_pears = 5
         self.n_grapefruit =7

     def __str__(self):
         self.shoppingList =""" 
         My Shopping List
         apples = %(n_apples)s
         pears = %(n_pears)s
         grapefruits = %(n_grapefruit)s
         """ %vars(self)
         return self.shoppingList


shopping = Shopping()
str(shopping) # calls your class's __str__(self) method
```

and lastly to generailse this class to contain all shopping needed you can use a `dict` and return `(key, value)` pairs so you don't have to define a variable for every product.

Comment: Excellent, both methods are appropriate for different situations